# SQL Developer Distinct gives ORA-00936

Tags: distinct, oracle-sqldeveloper

I try to create a query which gives me back how many customer has been registered to our system (using the REGISTERED_ID). However when a customer registrates he can then registrate again with a different car. I want to give back the amount of registers by month. I count the X__INSDATE because basicly I can count anything, all I need is a number. The error points to the DISTINCT, I tried to use having instead of where, but I may missed something.

I use Oracle SQL Developer 4.0.0.12

```
SELECT
  TRUNC(X__INSDATE, 'MONTH') as HONAP,
  COUNT(X__INSDATE),
  DISTINCT REGISTERED_ID
FROM
  DATABASE.data_history
WHERE
  DATABASE.data_history.X__INSDATE >= to_date('2013-JÚL. -01', 'YYYY-MON-DD')
GROUP BY TRUNC(X__INSDATE, 'MONTH') ORDER BY HONAP;
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply an aggregate function to all the clauses not on the grup by.

Try with:

```
SELECT
 TRUNC(X__INSDATE, 'MONTH') as HONAP,
 COUNT(X__INSDATE),
 COUNT(DISTINCT REGISTERED_ID)
```

Or by grouping as well by REGISTERED_ID

Comment: Thanks, adding registered_id to grop by still gives the same error. The Select you advised change the error to 00904 registered_id invalid identification.

Comment: I can actually just skip COUNT(X__INSDATE) since I would count the ID's don't I? (EDIT: Still the problem would persist, but at least the code is simplier)

Comment: I was stupid as hell... haven't change back registered_id to the actual column name... Sorry for that, what you suggested worked, and after checking out 3 return values it seems to work as intended. Thank you!